# "NameError: name 'insert' is not defined " when i try to use recursion in a method

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

```py
class Bst:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None
    
    def insert(self,data):
          
        if self.root==None:
            self.root=node(data)
        else:
            if data <= self.root.data:
                insert(self.root.left,data)
            else:
                insert(self.root.right,data)
```

Comment: `insert` is a class method. The syntax for calling class methods is slightly different than for calling functions. The first argument of the method plays a special role. We call it `self` to remind ourselves that it's special. You have to call `insert` as `some_bst_object.insert(data)`. In your case, `self.root.right.insert(data)`

Comment: yes thankyouu took me a while to figure that out.. apparently

Answer (score -1):

the code should had been like this

```
class BST():
def __init__(self):
    self.root=None
def insert(self,root,data):
        if root.data > data:
            if root.left==None:
                root.left=node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(root.left,data)
        else:
            if root.right==None:
                root.right=node(data)
            else:

                self.insert(root.right,data)
```

Comment: Could you please indicate where and why you changed the OP code?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: No, that's not very good. It's better to keep only two arguments, as originally in your question. Just replace the call `insert(self.root.left,data)` with `self.root.left.insert(data)`.